# how can I store inputted data asked for in a loop to a separate list each iteration?

Tags: python, loops, input

I'm writing a program that asks the user for a number of teams between 2 and 10, and then takes a team name and names of players on that team till the user enters done. it then moves onto the next teams name and players. finally, once done is entered for the final team it prints the name of each team and the name of the players on each team. the issue is I can't figure out how to store the names of the teams and the names of the players while the loop continues.

```
numteams = int(input("How many teams are there? "))
if numteams < 2 or numteams > 10:
    print("Please enter between 2 and 10 teams.")
#Ensures the proper number of teams are entered.
else:
    print("Please enter a team name when prompted. Then enter player names for that team. \nWhen done entering player names for that team, type done.")
    z = 1
    while z <= numteams:
    #overall loop to inquire about all teams
        teamname = input("Please enter the name of Team #" + str(z) + ": ")
        name = " "
        while name != "done":
        #loop to ask for names of players 
            name = input("Please enter the name of a player for team " + teamname + ": ")
        z = z + 1
```

this is my current code and it successfully asks for the names of the team and the names of the players based on how many teams there are but i don't know how to print each team and their players as each input variable is overwritten through each iteration of the loop. would a for-loop be more effective instead? i tried to create a list for each team but it also became overwritten as soon as the program looped again.

my goal output would appear as

Team #1: steelers

Player #1: bob

Player #2: joe

Team #2: dolphins

Player #1: timmy

Player #2: eli

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making only a minimal number of changes to your original code, we can add a dictionary to store team name as key and player names in a list as it value.

```
team_dict = {}

numteams = int(input("How many teams are there? "))
if numteams < 2 or numteams > 10:
    print("Please enter between 2 and 10 teams.")
    
#Ensures the proper number of teams are entered.
else:
    print("Please enter a team name when prompted. Then enter player names for that team. \nWhen done entering player names for that team, type done.")
    z = 1
    
    while z <= numteams:
        
        #overall loop to inquire about all teams
        teamname = input("Please enter the name of Team #" + str(z) + ": ")
        
        player_names = []
        player_name = ""
        
        #loop to ask for names of players
        while player_name != "done":
            
            player_name = input("Please enter the name of a player for team " + teamname + ": ")
            player_names.append(player_name)
            
        team_dict[teamname] = player_names
        
        z = z + 1
```

This generates a dictionary with the following data structure as described above

```
print(team_dict)

{'Yankees': ['Me', 'Myself', 'I', 'done'],
 'Pirates': ['Me again', 'Myself again', 'I again', 'done']}
```

We can then iterate over the teams and then player names for each entry and control how we print the output. For example

```
for key,val in team_dict.items():
    
    print(f"Team: {key}")
    
    for player in val:
        print(f"    Player: {player}")


# Team: Yankees
#     Player: Me
#     Player: Myself
#     Player: I
#     Player: done
# Team: Pirates
#     Player: Me again
#     Player: Myself again
#     Player: I again
#     Player: done
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I can't figure out how to store the names of the teams and the names of the players while the loop continues. ..."*

Declare an empty *collection* before the *for-loop*.

```py
teams = {}
while numteams := int(input("How many teams are there? ")):
    if not 2 <= numteams <= 10:
        print("Please enter between 2 and 10 teams.")
    else: break
#Ensures the proper number of teams are entered.
print("Please enter a team name when prompted. Then enter player names for that team. \nWhen done entering player names for that team, type done.")
for i in range(numteams):
    k = input(f'Team #{i + 1}: ')
    v = []
    j = 0
    while (p := input(f'Player #{(j := j + 1)}: ')) != "done":
        v.append(p)
    teams[k] = v
```

Output

```
How many teams are there? 2
Please enter a team name when prompted. Then enter player names for that team. 
When done entering player names for that team, type done.
Team #1: steelers
Player #1: bob
Player #2: joe
Player #3: done
Team #2: dolphins
Player #1: timmy
Player #2: eli
Player #3: done
{'steelers': ['bob', 'joe'], 'dolphins': ['timmy', 'eli']}
```